# Is this the correct way to hedge two securities against each other?

Tags: hedging, beta, pairs-trading

Let's say I believe that $ts_1$ and $ts_2$ move together and I would like to pairs trade them. Am I correct in understanding that to hedge them against each other I would get their $Var_1$, $Var_2$, and $Cov_1,_2$ all in USD, then I would buy 1000 USD worth of $ts_1$ and then find how much money to put into shorting $ts_2$ by doing $\beta =  Cov_1,_2$/$Var_1$, and then doing $\$\_position\_ts_2 = $\$1000* $\beta$?

Comment: What you are looking for is called the hedge ratio. For your formula to make sense, you need to be dividing by $\beta$.

Comment: Just to make sure I follow, you mean $USD\_position\_ts_2 = 1000 USD/ \beta$ where $\beta =  Cov_1,_2$/$Var_1$?

Answer (score 1):

This is (one way) how to hedge two securities against each other. I am synthesizing the material from [here](https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/how-to-calculate-the-beta-coefficient-for-a-single.aspx) and [here](http://thereformedbroker.com/2011/03/10/the-right-way-to-hedge/).

Let's call one security the $security_{market}$, and another $security_{unique}$. I'm taking for granted that you have done your research and believe that you found a good pair of securities for hedging.

1. Convert each security time-series from a price to a daily percent change. Call this $pct\_change_{market}$ and $pct\_change_{unique}$.
2. Get $Var(pct\_change_{market}$), $Var(pct\_change_{unique})$ and $Cov(pct\_change_{market}, pct\_change_{unique}$).
3. $\beta$ = $Cov(pct\_change_{market}, pct\_change_{unique}$)/$Var(pct\_change_{market}$).
4. Buy \$100,000 (or whatever amount) of $security_{unique}$. Now you need to know how many dollars to sink into $security_{market}$.
5. Multiply \$100,000 by the  $\beta$, this will be the amount of dollars to spend on your hedge.
6. Divide the number of dollars you came up with in step 5 by the price of $security_{market}$. Just to be clear, numerator is number of dollars, denominator is price of $security_{market}$. This will be your position for the hedge.

Note: Obviously, if you want to long one security then you will short the other security.